# Clothes simulation problem: clothes collision on another clothes

Tags: cloth-simulation

https://youtu.be/Y56eu1kO3pw

I made a clothes and a pants by sewing, and now I want to do animation, but after adding collision on my pants, my clothes still went through my pants, and it messed up the simulation of my clothes.

Both of them have solidify modifier, and the collision modifier of pants is placed between cloth modifier and solidify modifier. I followed this tutorial https://youtu.be/AbyfuW5Aocg , but it didn't work out the same way.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was due to the clothes colliding with the wrong face. When I sew clothes, I forgot to press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to correct the face normals.